# Looking for an 80's movie about a house obsessed with a girl?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

Here is the plot I can remember for a movie I saw on TV as a kid back in the 1980's. A girl grew up in a house and I think her family had lived there a long time. Somehow the house was "alive" and was obsessed with her and would kill/try to kill people that got to close to her. It would slam its black iron gates  repeatedly on its own for example.

All I can remember is that there was an older woman dressed in black towards the end who was scolding the girl about how much the house loved her and how she didn't appreciate that love or something along those lines. Then the next time you saw the old lady she was floating dead in the pool.

The ending was the girl standing outside the house screaming at the house for it" to let her go."

I am thinking this movie was made in the 70's or 80's.

Does any of this sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 20):

A TV movie from ABC in 1981 called [*This House Possessed*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083192/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

[Another site](http://www.retrojunk.com/content/article/7111/index/) describes how the plot unfolds.  In terms of your older woman in black:

> "The house loves you," says the Rag Lady. "It'll never let you go." Unfortunately, the Rag Lady isn't quite as loved. As soon as she finishes spouting off her story, a gust of wind appears from nowhere and knocks her into the scalding pool, where she quickly meets her demise. Cue commercial as Sheila/Margaret faints.

As far as the self-closing gate, and the final scream from the girl:

> Once outside, they're almost out of the driveway when the gates come crashing shut again. One would think that the gates would no longer be functional after crushing Lucille, but anyway... "Damn you!" Sheila screams at the house. An instant later, a cord of metal tubing flies out of the wall next to the gate and lassos Gary, then retracts, thunking him against the wall. As Gary takes the beating of his life, Sheila pleads with the burning house. "If you love me, you'd let him go -- you'd let me go!" The cord retracts, rolling Gary across the ground as it releases him. The gates fly open and the lovers embrace in front of the burning mansion.

Comment: Wow, Solemnity, thats it! Thank you so much!I love this website.I don't think I'd ever find the names of the tv shows and movies from my childhood  that I can only remember bits and pieces of on my own.

Comment: If it is correct, please click the checkmark beside my answers.  I wish I could be as helpful with your other questions, they're doozies.